# Resizing GXT Window When Browser Window Resizes

Tags: gxt

Developing using GXT 2.2.5 on GWT 2.3.0.

The application I'm working on displays a resizable Window with auto scrollbars. I want to make sure the Window size does not exceed the size of the browser window it gets displayed in. To that effect, I added the following code:

```
addWindowListener(new WindowListener()
{
  public void windowActivate(WindowEvent we)
  {
    super.windowActivate();
    Window window = we.getWindow();
    window.layout(true);
    int width = window.getWidth();
    int height = window.getHeight();
    int maxWidth = XDOM.getViewportWidth();
    int maxHeight = XDOM.getViewportHeight();
    window.setSize(Math.min(width, maxWidth), Math.min(height, maxHeight));
    window.center();
  }
};
```

This manages sizing the Window to fit in the browser when it gets opened quite nicely.

My problem is that if the user then resizes the browser window, the open Window does not adjust and ends up being clipped.

Is there some way for me to either force the Window to stay within the boundaries of the browser, or capture the resize event so that I can tell the Window to resize accordingly?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a viewport ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the listener (actually handler -- listeners got depreciated) to the browser window.

So if you have several different windows you show at different times that all need to be resized with the window, you need to have a listener for each window and add it to the browser window when the window is shown.

To add a listener to the browser Window, use:

```
com.google.gwt.user.client.Window.addResizeHandler(handler);
```

So for example to resize ContentPanel cp:

```
com.google.gwt.event.logical.shared.ResizeHandler handler = new ResizeHandler() {

        @Override public void onResize(com.google.gwt.event.logical.shared.ResizeEvent event) {

            cp.setWidth(event.getWidth());
            cp.setHeight(event.getHeight());

        }
    };
```

So then if you switch to a new view or ContentPanel you need to register that...

```
com.google.gwt.user.client.Window.addResizeHandler(handler2);

    com.google.gwt.event.logical.shared.ResizeHandler handler2 = new ResizeHandler() {

        @Override public void onResize(com.google.gwt.event.logical.shared.ResizeEvent event) {

            cp2.setWidth(event.getWidth());
            cp2.setHeight(event.getHeight());

        }
    };
```

NOTE:
You can't do event.getWindow() for the ResizeEvent you need to handle that another way.

Actually I tend to do it in a constructor like:

```
    com.google.gwt.event.logical.shared.ResizeHandler handler2;

     public MyDialog(){
     handler2 = new ResizeHandler() {

            @Override public void onResize(com.google.gwt.event.logical.shared.ResizeEvent event) {

                 setWidth(event.getWidth());
                 setHeight(event.getHeight());

            }
        };
```

Comment: This doesn't work because it's not the Window that's being resized, it's the browser. Resizing the browser does not automatically resize any displayed windows.

Comment: see my revision.  This should work for sure.  I moved to gxt3 so don't remember the exact code... maybe you need to sink and event or maybe you need to resize the container...the revised code above works for me in gxt3 by resizing the container.

Comment: Well, it doesn't work in GXT 2.2.5. Again, to be clear, I'm not resizing the displayed window, I'm resizing the browser, and that does not trigger a Resize event for the Window. I could try to sink an event, but I don't know what GWT event to use.

Comment: try Window.addListener( Events.Resize, new Listener<WindowEvent>() {...});

Comment: I don't think we're communicating well here. What window am I adding the Listener to? For the third time, adding it to the window that's popping up does not work.

Comment: To add a listener (or handler) to the browser Window use com.google.gwt.user.client.Window (see my revised code)